# Analytical solution to a parametric variable integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I am looking for an analytical solution to the integral
$$
I(n) = \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-x-x^2-x^3-x^4-x^5} x^n{\rm d}x.
$$
This integral converges numerically, and I am looking for an analytical result. Could you give me some suggestions or ideas (but not the answers), which can help me to find the final result. Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered writing the exponent under the form $-x\dfrac{1-x^5}{1-x}$ ? I don't know if it can have any interest...

Comment: @Professor Marie: Many thanks for your valuable suggestions! I have tried to use the Gamma function to figure out the analytical solution, but I have not tried to write the exponent in the form that you provide.

Comment: IMHO: it's very doubtful there exists an **analytical** solution with a degree $>2$ polynomial in the exponent (below degree $3$, yes, $\Gamma$ function can provide solutions).

Comment: Thank you, Professor Marie: I am wondering why a degree >2 polynomial in the exponent is likely to have no analytical solution. Is there any theory behind this judgment?

Comment: See the very interesting answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2004468) mentionning the Liouville theorem. I have obtained this reference by using the formula searching tool [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/) with $\int_0^{\infty}x^ne^{-P(x)}dx$

Comment: An interesting document:http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/elemint.pdf

Comment: This said, we can be in a situation where, in a provable way, no primitive function exist whereas the integral from $0$ to $\infty$ has a closed form expression (for example by using complex integration).

Comment: Thank you, Professor Marie: I need some time to learn the valuable material. Moreover, the formula searching tool is very helpful.